# Corda Accounts Limit per Node

Tags: corda, account

I am new to Corda and I was just trying to understand if an accounts approach is suitable for what I want to achieve.

My doubts regarding this are:

- Is there a maximum limit of account number per node?
- Does the accounts number per node impact the network performance?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Account at the end of the day are states in Corda, which few more stuff like public and some mappings. Thus there isn't a limit to the number of states you could really create as long as your disk space permits. Or perhaps say you hit the barrier of the number of keys you could generate, which is unrealistic.

Accounts should not have any noticeable impact on network performance.